# How to find duplicated rows when only time part of POSIXct column is different?

Tags: r, data.table

I have some rows, where time part of POSIXct column is missed (=equal to 00:00:00). How should I find duplicated rows where only time is different?

If I use the code like below:

```
dataDuplicates <- data[duplicated(data, by = NULL) | duplicated(data, by = NULL, fromLast = TRUE), ]
```

then it will not find such cases.

If I use the following code:

```
setkey(data, <all fields are there except that data field>, physical = TRUE)
dataDuplicates <- data[duplicated(data) | duplicated(data, fromLast = TRUE), ]
```

then it will find cases when even the date is different.

Here is the code for testing:

```
zz <- "or,d,ddate,rdate,changes,class,price,fdate,company,number,minutes,added,source
VA3,VA4,2014-05-24 12:23:00,,0,0,2124,2014-05-22 15:50:16,,,,2014-05-22 12:20:03,ss
VA1,VA2,2014-05-26 14:00:01,,0,0,2124,2014-05-22 15:03:44,,,,2014-05-22 12:20:03,s1
VA1,VA2,2014-05-26 00:00:00,,0,0,2124,2014-05-22 15:03:44,,,,2014-05-22 12:20:03,s1
VA1,VA2,2014-05-27 14:00:01,,0,0,2124,2014-05-22 15:03:44,,,,2014-05-22 12:20:03,s1
VA5,VA6,2014-06-05 18:00:04,,0,0,2124,2014-05-22 15:48:24,,,,2014-05-22 12:20:03,s1
VA7,VA8,2014-06-09 18:00:07,,0,0,2124,2014-05-22 15:37:35,,,,2014-05-22 12:20:03,s2
VA9,VA0,2014-06-16 19:00:20,,0,0,2124,2014-05-22 14:17:33,,,,2014-05-22 12:20:03,ss"

columnClasses <- c("factor", "factor", "POSIXct", "factor", "integer", "factor", "integer", "factor", "factor", "factor", "integer", "factor", "factor")
data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE, sep = ",", comment.char = "", quote = "", na.strings = c(""), colClasses = columnClasses)
```

The valid code should return rows 2 and 3 as duplicated rows.

Comment: `data[duplicated(as.Date(ddate)) | duplicated(as.Date(ddate), fromLast = TRUE)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert the 'ddate' column to 'Date' class and use that for finding the `duplicate` rows.

```
d1 <- cbind(data[-3],as.Date(data$ddate))
data[duplicated(d1)|duplicated(d1, fromLast=TRUE),]
#     or   d               ddate rdate changes class price               fdate
#2 VA1 VA2 2014-05-26 14:00:01  <NA>       0     0  2124 2014-05-22 15:03:44
#3 VA1 VA2 2014-05-26 00:00:00  <NA>       0     0  2124 2014-05-22 15:03:44
#  company number minutes               added source
#2    <NA>   <NA>      NA 2014-05-22 12:20:03     s1
#3    <NA>   <NA>      NA 2014-05-22 12:20:03     s1
```

Answer (score 0):

data[duplicated(format(data$ddate, "%Y-%M-%d")) | duplicated(format(data$ddate, "%Y-%M-%d"), fromLast=TRUE),]

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.